# How to set Properties by Interface and not get compilerwarnings

Tags: c#, .net-core, compiler-warnings, .net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

I have a lot of classes that share a lot of properites and have a lot of common interfaces.
It happens very regularly that i want to construct an object with data from another object and they share an interface. To make that more easy i have this neat little method:

```
public static List<PropertyInfo> InterfaceProperties(Type type)
{
    return new[] {type}
        .Concat(type.GetInterfaces())
        .SelectMany(i => i.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)).ToList();
}
public static void SetFromSimilar<TInterface>(TInterface destination,TInterface source)     
{
    var properties = InterfaceProperties(typeof(TInterface));
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var val = property.GetValue(source, null);
        property.SetValue(destination, val, null);
    }
}
```

It works fantastic because now i can do this:

```
public class MyClass: IMyInterface
{
    public MyClass(IMyInterface otherClass)
    {
        SetFromSimilar(this,otherClass)
    }
    ....MyProperties.....
}
```

Now rider complains about non-nullable properties being uninitialized which makes sense. I know they are initialized but for the IDE thats hard to see and i get compilerwarnings. This throws me off because i see it marked as a potentialy error and i have to think everytime if there is something wrong.
Is there a substitute for my method where this will not happen?

---

Ok i got no answers so far. Is it not possible? Is this not a normal usecase? Is it somehow possible with net5?

---

The compiler warning:

```
C:\My\File\Path\MyClass.cs(10,16): warning CS8618: Non-Nullable-Eigenschaft "MyProperty" muss     beim Beenden des Konstruktors einen Wert ungleich NULL enthalten.
Erwägen Sie eine Deklaration von "Eigenschaft" als Nullable. [C:\My\File\Path\MyProject.csproj]
```

It tells me to maybe make the property nullable which i absolutely don`t want.

Comment: one interesting (but non-trivial) possibility to fix @PanagiotisKanavos's observations would be to write a C# 9 "generator" that detects `SetFromSimilar<T>(T, T)` invocations, and generates a non-generic `SetFromSimilar(SpecificType, SpecificType)` that *iterates over the properties and does what is needed in the generated code*

Comment: @MarcGravell i would be realy interested in that. Should i ask a new question for that?

Comment: you could, but it is a non-trivial question in a *very* new API...

Comment: @MarcGravell sounds interesting and exciting to try. But probably not something for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler and analyzers cannot usually (or easily) interpret reflection code, so it is quite reasonably unconvinced as to their assignment and nullability. If you know something is correct that the compiler can't verify: just add a suppression for the warning over that particular code block, via `#pragma`, a `[SuppressMessage(...)]` on the affected code, or a suppression file (which is just `[assembly:SuppressMessage(...)]` in a different file, with a `Target` to tell the compiler what it applies to). Rider may have some other ways of suppressing messages, via the context menu.

Note: if you go this route, you may also want to add assertions - especially in a `DEBUG` build - that what you belive to be true: is actually true.

If you're using C# 9, you *could* add a smattering of dammit (`!`) markers, or turn off nullability checking for that code.

Answer (score 1):

Well yea, this does not look like a perfectly elegant solution to your problem, in my opinion. Here's some solutions I can think of, in order of elegance:

**1. Quick & Brute force**

Just tell rider to not complain about it with a #pragma statement, I believe in your case it should be this:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8618
[code that throws the warning]
#pragma warning restore CS8618
```

**2. Write code to generate code**

Write yourself a small application that extracts those common interfaces to autogenerate set-value code for each

**3. Don't mix data with control code**

If you need to set data on classes with different controllers, i.e. classes, put it into its own data class. Tadaaa, you just gained the ability of class inheritance for setting common values.

Comment: on 3: normaly i would agree but the thing is this is a very common pattern in my code because of a legacydatabase with a lot of tables that are not normalized with ton of fields and i need a generic solution where i dont even need to write the constructor for all thos fields once. I would be very interested in your second idea.

Comment: Well you already have some code that iterate over all public interfaces, you can easily print that to a .cs file, with some bits of handcrafted C# code around it, then add the file to visual studio.

If the interfaces change often, make it a post build event to auto-generate those files each build.

Comment: I do the same to generate C# code from GLSL shader source, so I can interface with them easily